# Get ID Banner and Interstitial with SharedPreferences editText

Tags: java

I build app for admob test with user input ID. I want get admob banner ID and Interstitial ID with Edit Text SharedPreferences. my question how to get banner and Interstitial ?

XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BannerID"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Interstitial_ID" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtInterstitial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reward ID" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtReward"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Keyword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtAppid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAVE" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And ActivitySetting.java For XML Activity_seting.xml

```
public class ActivitySeting extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Button btnSave;
EditText edtBanner, edtInterstitial, edtReward;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_seting );

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences( "DataID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    edtBanner = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.edtBanner );
    edtInterstitial = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.edtInterstitial );
    edtReward = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.edtReward );
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnSave );
    btnSave.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString( "banner", edtBanner.getText().toString() );
            editor.putString( "Interstitial", edtInterstitial.getText().toString() );
            editor.putString( "Reward", edtReward.getText().toString() );
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

}
}
```

I want call ID and Interstitial with sharedPreferences in ActivityNew.java But I don't knw. Can you give me example for ActivityNew.java?

before I use string.xml for get R.id.Banner_test and interstitial in ActivityNew.java